# Parsing JSON with curly and straight quotes

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to make an app using a specific API, but the problem is the response is quite tricky. Most of the keys and values are inside straight quotes (") except for one. One of the values starts with a curly quote (“) and ends with the straight quote("). Using JSONDecoder and codable is not working.

Any work around for this one without modifying the response on server side?

I tried replacing occurences of curly quotes with straight quotes only to find that some of the values are using curly quotes inside them so it wont work.

Comment: That doesn't sound like proper json, maybe contact the publisher of the API and have them fix the issue?

Comment: I agree with Joakim. That sounds like badly formed JSON. There are various online JSON parsers/validators. I suggest copying the data from this server into one of those, and then using the error it likely gives as proof to the server owner that the data is malformed.

Comment: Sounds like you may know which property it is. If so, you can probably run a RegEx on the original data to switch that one property, but, like you already discovered, a global replace won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You my need to fiddle with regular expressions, things like:

`^“` for curly quotes in the start of fields, and `“$` for curly quotes in the end of words. This way you can match only curly quotes that start or end of key/values of your JSON. It shouldn't be very complex to pinpoint and replace them with today's languages support for REGEX and text substitutions.

Answer (score -1):

First, you absolutely should fix the server. This is invalid JSON.

If you can't fix the server, a substitution based on your knowledge of the format is probably the right thing. Look for something like `/“[^"]*"/:` as a regex to look for a smart quote followed by a bunch of non-`"`, followed by `"` followed immediately by `:`. Maybe in your particular case that will happen to work.

But these are boring answers. Let's do it the hard way and validate some JSON by hand, and fix this one special case (smart quote at the beginning of a key).

One tool you could use is a JSON tokenizer. For something fairly off-the-shelf (but not particularly supported), see [RNJSON](https://github.com/rnapier/RNJSON). After importing with:

```
    .package(url: "https://github.com/rnapier/RNJSON", branch: "main"),
```

The following would rewrite your JSON:

```
let tokenizer = JSONTokenizer()
var json = originalJSON[...]
var outJSON = Data()
let smartQuote = "“".utf8

while !json.isEmpty {
    // Grab a token and append it
    let result = try tokenizer.firstToken(from: json)
    outJSON.append(result.data)
    json.removeFirst(result.length)

    // If the next token may be a key, drop whitespace, and if there's a smart-quote, replace it
    if result is JSONTokenObjectOpen || result is JSONTokenListSeparator {
        // Drop whitespace
        try json.trimPrefix(while: { [0x09, 0x0a, 0x0d, 0x20].contains($0) })
        if json.starts(with: smartQuote) {
            let range = json.startIndex..<json.index(json.startIndex, offsetBy: smartQuote.count)
            json.replaceSubrange(range, with: "\"".utf8)
        }
    }
}
```

RNJSON is a toy of mine (as is the closely related [RNAJSON](https://github.com/rnapier/RNAJSON)), and I don't recommend relying on the full package. I recommend just copying what you need and learning from it.

So another way to approach this is to parse it directly. It's a lot more code, but it's a good introduction to really simple parsing. This code does not try to carefully validate the JSON. It does the minimum it can to make sure it's at an object-key before looking for smart-quotes. Other than that, it assumes a later parser will check the details.

The key block of code for this problem is:

```
               // Detect smart quotes 0xe2, 0x80, 0x9c and replace with "  \""
            case 0xe2 where awaiting.contains(.objectKey) && peekAhead(2, is: [0x80, 0x9c]):
                let startRange = self.index(before: index)
                let endRange = self.index(after: index)
                self[startRange...endRange] = SubSequence("  \"".utf8)
```

Here's the full function to your specific problem.

```
enum JSONError: Swift.Error, Hashable {
    case unexpectedCharacter(ascii: UInt8)
    case unexpectedEndOfFile
}

private enum Awaiting: Hashable {
    case start, end
    case objectKey, keyValueSeparator, objectValue, objectSeparator, objectClose
    case arrayValue, arraySeparator, arrayClose
}

private enum Container { case object, array }

extension MutableDataProtocol {
    mutating func fixLeadingSmartQuotesOnJSONKeys() throws {
        var index = startIndex
        var containers: [Container] = []
        var awaiting: Set<Awaiting> = [.start]
        let digitCharacters = "0123456789-+.eE".utf8

        while let byte = nextByte() {
            switch byte {
            case UInt8(ascii: "\t"), UInt8(ascii: "\n"), UInt8(ascii: "\r"), UInt8(ascii: " "):
                break

            case UInt8(ascii: "{") where !awaiting.isDisjoint(with: [.start, .objectValue, .arrayValue]):
                containers.append(.object)
                awaiting = [.objectKey, .objectClose]

            case UInt8(ascii: "\"") where awaiting.contains(.objectKey):
                awaiting = [.keyValueSeparator]
                try consumeOpenString()

            case UInt8(ascii: ":") where awaiting.contains(.keyValueSeparator):
                awaiting = [.objectValue]

            case UInt8(ascii: ",") where awaiting.contains(.objectSeparator):
                awaiting = [.objectKey, .objectClose]

            case UInt8(ascii: "}") where containers.last == .object && awaiting.contains(.objectClose):
                popContainer()

            case UInt8(ascii: "[") where !awaiting.isDisjoint(with: [.start, .objectValue, .arrayValue]):
                containers.append(.array)
                awaiting = [.arrayValue, .arrayClose]

            case UInt8(ascii: ",") where awaiting.contains(.arraySeparator):
                awaiting = [.arrayValue, .arrayClose]

            case UInt8(ascii: "]") where containers.last == .array && awaiting.contains(.arrayClose):
                popContainer()

                // Detect smart quotes 0xe2, 0x80, 0x9c and replace with "  \""
            case 0xe2 where awaiting.contains(.objectKey) && peekAhead(2, is: [0x80, 0x9c]):
                let startRange = self.index(before: index)
                let endRange = self.index(after: index)
                self[startRange...endRange] = SubSequence("  \"".utf8)

            case _ where awaiting.contains(.objectValue):
                awaiting = [.objectSeparator, .objectClose]
                try consumeScalarValue(first: byte)

            case _ where awaiting.contains(.arrayValue):
                awaiting = [.arraySeparator, .arrayClose]
                try consumeScalarValue(first: byte)

            case _ where awaiting.contains(.start):
                awaiting = [.end]
                try consumeScalarValue(first: byte)

            default:
                throw JSONError.unexpectedCharacter(ascii: byte)
            }
        }

        func peekAhead(_ count: Int, is value: [UInt8]) -> Bool {
            self[index...].prefix(count).elementsEqual(value)
        }

        func consumeOpenString() throws {
            while let byte = nextByte() {
                switch byte {
                case UInt8(ascii: "\""): return

                    // This intentionally doesn't worry about \u as a special case.
                    // It'll just be handled as more of string. The only reason for this
                    // test is to handle escaped close-quotes.
                case UInt8(ascii: "\\"): try consume(count: 1)

                default: break
                }
            }
            throw JSONError.unexpectedEndOfFile
        }

        func popContainer() {
            containers.removeLast()
            switch containers.last {
            case .none: awaiting = [.end]
            case .some(.object): awaiting = [.objectSeparator, .objectClose]
            case .some(.array): awaiting = [.arraySeparator, .arrayClose]
            }
        }

        func consumeScalarValue(first: UInt8) throws {
            switch first {
            case UInt8(ascii: "\""): try consumeOpenString()
            case UInt8(ascii: "-"), UInt8(ascii: "0")...UInt8(ascii: "9"): try consumeDigits()
            case UInt8(ascii: "t"): try consumeOpenLiteral("true")
            case UInt8(ascii: "f"): try consumeOpenLiteral("false")
            case UInt8(ascii: "n"):try consumeOpenLiteral("null")
            default: throw JSONError.unexpectedCharacter(ascii: first)
            }
        }

        func consumeDigits() throws {
            while let byte = nextByte(), digitCharacters.contains(byte) {}
            formIndex(before: &index) // Back-up one character
        }

        func consume(count: Int) throws {
            for _ in 0..<count where nextByte() == nil {
                throw JSONError.unexpectedEndOfFile
            }
        }

        func consumeOpenLiteral(_ literal: String) throws {
            try consume(count: literal.count - 1)
        }

        func nextByte() -> UInt8? {
            guard index != endIndex else { return nil }
            let currentIndex = index
            formIndex(after: &index)
            return self[currentIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He, your RNJSON package looks very useful, despite you having made it jut for fun. But isn't it a bit of an overkill to the problem at hand? Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @otaviokz If you have a solution that is shorter and fully solves the problem (including not replacing smart quotes in **arbitrary** keys and string values), I am all for that. I can kind of imagine a regex that will handle it, but I haven't built and proven one. It's certainly worth exploration. `/^“/` definitely isn't enough. My `/“[^"]*"/:` isn't enough either (it doesn't protect against embedded backslash). I only suggest RNJSON because it lets you do it in a dozen lines of code rather than a hundred, but that's why I also offered the full, self-contained solution with no dependencies.

Comment: @Bob  Napier, it was my understanding that the question involved only curly quotes in the beginning of a value, that's why I suggested simply using regexes to replace curly quotes in the beginning or ending of keys or values. But you're right when you say it's not a full solution if we consider the possibility of said curly quotes appearing in the middle of a string instead of surrounding it.

Comment: The question was just for curly quotes at the start of keys (not at the end of keys, and not in the middle of strings; "I tried replacing occurences of curly quotes with straight quotes only to find that some of the values are using curly quotes inside them so it wont work."). `^` matches the start of a line, not the start of a field (I'm not sure what "field" means in this context; JSON doesn't do it that way). I do think a regex is probably the most reasonable answer for a known data format where you can be certain pathological cases don't show up, but for a general case you need to parse.

Comment: I lost that vital detail detail. Josleyn Santos do you have exemple of such JSON files (with on real data of course) so me and Rob can fiddle with it and try to find a reliable solution? (I mean, if one of Rob hasn't alreeady fixed your probem. Cheers